# Do-Calculus in Python or R

Tags: machine-learning, probability, python, causality

Are there any packages for implementing Judea Pearl's "Do-Calculus" in Python or R? If they exist, I'd love to hear about them.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/causaleffect/vignettes/causaleffect.pdf